# How to create list and detail view using React Router DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new in React and doesn't know how to create List and Detail view using React Router DOM. Some how I created it but I know this is not a good way to do it. If you look into below code, you will find it will always reload the whole page if I select another campaign. What will be the good way to do it. Please help...

App.js

```
<Switch> 
   <Fragment>
       <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/campaigns/:id" component={CampaignComponent}/>
       <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/campaigns/:id/messages" component={CampaignComponent}/>
       <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/campaigns/:id/contacts" component={CampaignComponent}/>
   </Fragment>
</Switch>
```

Campaign.js

```
let layout;

switch (props.match.path) {
      case '/admin/campaigns/:id':
        layout = <CampaignDetailComponent props={props}/>;
        break;

      case '/admin/campaigns/:id/messages':
        layout = <CampaignMessageListComponent props={props}/>;
        break;

      case '/admin/campaigns/:id/contacts':
        layout = <CampaignContactListComponent props={props}/>;
        break;

      default:
        layout = <div/>;
}


return (
     <div>
          <div className="col-6">
            <CampaignListComponent props={props}/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-6">
            {layout}
          </div>
     </div>
)
```

So, in the first `col-6` I want to show the list of Campaigns and in second `col-6` I want to render the components as per route change.

You can follow [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-microservice-8ktzq) to see the actual working code sample that demonstrate this issue.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? Is `Campaign` the `CampaignComponent` in `App.js`? If we can see more of your component/app structure we may be better able to resolve. Can you clarify what you mean by "reloads the whole page"?

Comment: Yes @DrewReese, ```Campaign``` is the ```CampaignComponent``` in ```App.js```. Reloads means, when I click on any campaign from the list, it's reloading the complete web page not only the detail view that I want to change. I will try to create a sandbox example of my issue and update my question here.

Comment: That would be great. I'd like to see how you are linking to your routes.

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated my question to add sandbox link. Kindly have a look. Looking for support :)

Comment: So your app structure is a little odd, IMO, but navigating around I don't notice any complete page reloading (I suspect we don't have the same interpretation of what a whole page reload is). From what I can see, the `CampaignListComponent` is your navigation component in the left panel, and `CampaignComponent` is the right side. Every `CampaignComponent` renders a copy of the link list. The campaign seen in the right side matches the current route. It's unclear to me what the issue is. Can you describe what you expect the behavior to be when navigating around?

Comment: Yes, I agree!! App structure is completely odd. Your suggestion on it is appreciated!! 
I think that's true we don't have the same interpretation about page reload. Let me explain you what I want. In ```App.js``` I want only one route that will navigate to ```CampaignComponent``` and all other routes should be in ```CampaignComponent```. In ```CampaignComponent``` I have two panels, left have the ```CampaignListComponent``` and I want child routes to be inside right panel that will render components according to the URL.

Comment: In current scenario what happening is, when I click on any campaign from the ```CampaignListComponent``` or I click on Goto Messages/Goto Contacts button It's navigating to ```CampaignComponent``` and here I'm showing component conditionally. So everytime it's calling the parent component and view is re-creating. What I want is when user clicks on any campaign from ```CampaignListComponent``` It should only re-create the detail panel not the other components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

You have your "navigation" coupled to your page UI.

## Solution

Split out the rendering of your links in the left section from the content in the right section. The rest of the changes a centered around computing paths and route structuring.

App.js

Render the campaign list container and navigation on its own route. This is so the nested links can inherit from the route path.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { HashRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import CampaignComponent from "./Campaign/Campaign";
import CampaignListComponent from "./Campaign/Components/CampaignList";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Sample app to demonstrate React Router issue</h3>
        <HashRouter>
          <div className="campaign-container">
            <div className="campaign-list">
              <Route path="/admin/campaigns">
                <CampaignListComponent />
              </Route>
            </div>
            <div className="campaign-detail">
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/admin/campaigns" component={CampaignComponent} />
                <Redirect from="*" to="/admin/campaigns" />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Campaign list component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, generatePath, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const CampaignListComponent = () => {
  const [campaignList, setCampaignList] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Campaign1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Campaign2" },
    { id: 3, name: "Campaign3" },
    { id: 4, name: "Campaign4" },
    { id: 5, name: "Campaign5" }
  ]);
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "90%" }}>
      {campaignList.map(({ id, name }) => (
        <div className="campaign-list-item" key={id}>
          <Link to={generatePath(`${url}/:id`, { id })}>{name}</Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Campaign component

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

import CampaignMessageListComponent from "./Components/CampaignMessageList";
import CampaignDetailComponent from "./Components/CampaignDetail";
import CampaignContactListComponent from "./Components/CampaignContactList";

const CampaignComponent = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div className="campaign-list">
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path={`${path}/:id/messages`}
          component={CampaignMessageListComponent}
        />
        <Route
          path={`${path}/:id/contacts`}
          component={CampaignContactListComponent}
        />
        <Route path={`${path}/:id`} component={CampaignDetailComponent} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Content components

Contact

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const CampaignContactListComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <p>Campaign Contact List</p>
      <button onClick={history.goBack}>Go Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Message

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const CampaignMessageListComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <p>Campaign Message List</p>
      <button onClick={history.goBack}>Go Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Detail

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useHistory, useParams, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const CampaignDetailComponent = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div>
      <h6>Campaign Detail</h6>
      <p>You have selected Campaign - {id}</p>
      <button>
        <Link to={`${url}/messages`}>Goto Messages</Link>
      </button>
      <button>
        <Link to={`${url}/contacts`}>Goto Contacts</Link>
      </button>
      <button onClick={history.goBack}>Go Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-create-list-and-detail-view-using-react-router-dom]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Drew, it's really very helpful but I have a confusion. Here, ```App.js``` is responsible to show ```CampaignListComponent``` in left panel and other components in right panel. What if I have some more routes in ```App.js``` that have completely different view?

Comment: @AbhishekRaj You can factor everything that is in the `"campaign-container"` container div into a component and render *that* component on a route with path like "/admin". I updated the sandbox with a simple factoring.